# Return a default row if nothing is found

Tags: mysql, default

I have a query that will return data assuming `members.language_id` is greater than zero and a supported language. If a member does not have a language selected `members.language_id` defaults to zero, which isn't helpful when joining on another table (keep in mind I didn't design this table structure and I can't change it).

So, what I would like to do is when no result comes back default to a result where:
`t.code = 'Kount_Declined' and t.language_id = 1`

```
select m.email, t.subject, t.message from orders o
join members m using(member_id)
join languages l using(language_id)
join emailtempl t on t.language_id = GREATEST(l.language_id, 1)
where o.transaction_id = '3TK904KVMM8X'
and t.code = 'Kount_Declined'
```

Is there any way that I can do this? I understand that I could do this with 2 queries, but is there a way to do it without the extra query?

Comment: sql 'union' with the default and limit 1 on the whole query?

Comment: @TheBoogieMan have you checked my edit with the `IF` ?

Comment: @RyanVincent So far your answer works the best for everything that I am looking for, you should post an answer.

Comment: @RyanVincent I was just giving you the opportunity to earn some points.... If you don't want it I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try a modified join condition

```
    select m.email, t.subject, t.message
      from orders o
      join members m      using(member_id)
      join emailtempl t   on t.language_id = GREATEST(o.language_id, 1)
     where o.transaction_id = '3TK904KVMM8X'
       and t.code = 'Kount_Declined'
         ;
```

Comment: Just found a problem... if a language is set that we don't support (such as an id of 1000), no value is returned...

Comment: I see, a suitable alternative has been proposed by RyanVincent.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `IF`

```
select m.email, t.subject, t.message
from orders o
join members m using(member_id)
join emailtempl t on o.language_id = IF(t.language_id = 0, 1, t.language_id)
where o.transaction_id = '3TK904KVMM8X'
and t.code = 'Kount_Declined';
```

Comment: A left join will just return null's

Comment: Then you can use an `IF` to return what you want when null

Comment: I would prefer using an if than greatest as it is more clear we are actually doing a validation, while using greatest may let someone else think it is always wanted and won't understand it is because of 0s.

Comment: That doesn't work. We don't support language id 1000, and if I use it I get no results back, and for some reason using 0 gives no results back either. btw `language_id` is in all tables except for `orders`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@RyanVincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent) for suggesting that I use a `union` with a `limit 1`, I was then able to come up with this, and it has passed all the tests that I was looking for to accomplish this feat.

```
(
    select t.language_id, m.email, t.subject, t.message from orders o
    join members m using(member_id)
    join languages l using(language_id)
    join emailtempl t using(language_id)
    where o.transaction_id = '3TK904KVMM8X'
    and t.code = 'Kount_Declined' limit 1
)
union
(
    select t.language_id, m.email, t.subject, t.message from orders o
    join members m using(member_id)
    join emailtempl t on t.language_id = 1
    where o.transaction_id = '3TK904KVMM8X'
    and t.code = 'Kount_Declined' limit 1
)
limit 1
```